# PHPstorm misbehaving with jQuery calls with a colon in the selector

Tags: phpstorm

When I type the following:

```
$(".cls
```

the ending quote is already filled in, closing the quote will skip over the one that's already there, but when I type this:

```
$(".cls:eq(0)
```

and then close the qoute PHPStorm will add two quotes, so I end up with this:

```
$(".cls:eq(0)""")
```

which is not correct... Does anybody know how to solve this? Recently switched from 6 to 7.1.2. Of course skipping the quote with the cursor would solve this, but it is a distraction from programming if you have to think about skipping a quote with a cursor in case I'm making a jQuery call with a colon in the selector (cause that seems to cause it)..

Comment: Sounds like a relatively obscure issue. Might have more luck on the [Jetbrains devnet forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/wi?view=discussions)

Comment: If you type closing quote and closing bracket **anyway** ... why don't you then simply disable inserting it in first place? As for *possible reason* for such behaviour .. it most likely because you already have closing bracket `)` and IDE wrongly thinks that it is outside of the original bracket. If my suggestion (about turning off that feature) is not good .. then you should report the issue to their bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: Done, thanks for the advise: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/453066